# linearize a nonlinear ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Could anyone suggest me how to linearize the following system of nonlinear odes (special attention to (2)
\begin{align}
    -cU'&=-U''+UV\tag{1}\\
 -cV'&=-k(k+1)V^{k-1}(V')^2+(k+1)V^k V''+UV-\mu V-\gamma V^2\tag{2}
\end{align}

?

Take $V=V(x)$, $U=U(x)$, $\mu$, $\gamma$ arbitrary constants. $k$ takes integer values.

Comment: what is $U$? a constant?

Comment: Usually you linearize around a fixed point to the equation.  Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

using 
\begin{align}
V(x) = V_0 + \delta V,\\
U(x) = U_0 + \delta U.
\end{align}

we find the linearized equations are
$$
-c\delta U' = -\delta U'' + U_0\delta V + V_0\delta U + U_0V_0,\\
-c\delta V' = \left(U_0V_0 - \mu V_0 -\gamma V_0^2\right) + \left(U_0 -\mu -2V_0\right)\delta V\\
+(k+1)V_0^k\delta V'' + V_0\delta U
$$
From the first equation the equilibrium point occurs at $U_0V_0=0$ and therefore the first linearized equation is 
$$
-c\delta U' = -\delta U'' + U_0\delta V + V_0\delta U.
$$
The second equation the eqluibrium points is given by
$$
U_0V_0 - \mu V_0 -\gamma V_0^2 =0
$$
which leads to the linearized equation 
$$
-c\delta V' = \left(U_0 -\mu -2V_0\right)\delta V +(k+1)V_0^k\delta V'' + V_0\delta U
$$
where the $V_0,U_0$ are constants. Though if you mean using 
$$
V(x) = \tilde{V}(x) + \delta V
$$
and linearize in that fashion then you can go through that yourself following the same convention with the exception that $\tilde{V}(x),\tilde{U}(x)$ are solutions of the original equation.

$\textbf{Appendix}$
To further expand on how I arrived at the above linear form. lets take 
$$
cU' = -U'' + UV (1).
$$
we find the equilibrium points by setting the derivatives to zero as follows
$$
0 = -0 + UV\implies UV = U_0V_0 = 0
$$
The other equation will also yield an equilibrium equation which is set to zero. In the above I have been cheeky and not explicitly determined what the equilibrium points are, but in most cases I have come across you do not need to know that explicitly to form the linearised equations.
so continuing we have equations of the form $f = f_0 + \delta f$ (as above)
inserting into the Eq.(1) we find 
\begin{align}
-c\left(U_0'+\delta U'\right) = -\left(U_0''+\delta U''\right)\\
+\left(U_0+\delta U\right)\left(V_0+\delta V\right)
\end{align}
But the terms $f_0'$ are zero(since $f_0$ are constants) so we can further reduce.
$$
-c\delta U' = -\delta U''\\
+U_0V_0 +U_0\delta V + \delta U V_0 + \delta U\delta V
$$
Now we linearise by neglecting terms of $O(\delta f^2)$ and higher
$$
-c\delta U' = -\delta U'' + U_0V_0 +U_0\delta V + \delta U V_0 
$$

Can you take it from here? and also do the second equation?

Analogously, the second equation would become
$$
-c\delta V'=(k+1)V_0^k\delta V''+U_0 V_0-\mu V_0-\gamma V_0^2+(U_0-\mu-2V_0)\delta V+\delta UV_0
$$
?

Note that in the first term of rhs, we have $(k+1)V_0^k\delta V''$ instead of $(k+1)(V_0+\delta V)^k\delta V''$ since we are ignoring the higher power terms in the binomial expansion.

Comment: Could you provide some general references for the method you  suggested?

Comment: Also, how to find critical points of a second order nonlinear couple system of ode in GENERAL? (exclude the obvious cases which can be done by inspection)

Comment: i can follow your logic in finding the equilibrium points, but in order to deal with other similar problems, could you pls provide a standard reference on the suggested method of finding equilibrium points

Comment: @math101 I will try dig some refs out, though this particular stuff was mainly taught on undergrad and not to much to it.  I will also flesh out my answer with more workings in out.

Comment: that would be helpful. There are several versions of linearization techniques for nonlinear pde/ode and I got confused when is appropriate to use which...

Comment: Nonlinear Waves, Solitons and Chaos [Eryk Infeld, George Rowlands] this was the text I used for all that linearising(he was also my advisor on my phd awesome lad)! There is a difference between pde and ode linearising. We should also take this to chat after I made mods to answer.

Comment: appreciate for that, but it will take me few month to read a copy of the text you suggested. so would be great if you could elaborate your answer a bit. Most of the linearisation methods in applied pde literature are very ad-hoc (though i know for nonlinear pde this is unavoidable...)